# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$. Then there is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that diverges to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm not sure how to go about this. I think I am supposed to use the definition of limit superior, but I do not know how to incorporate this. I barely have anything useful, all I have is:

We will start by assuming $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, and we will let $x_{p_n}$ be any subsequence of $\{x_n\}$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What is your definition of limit superior? There are different definitions. The one in Baby Rudin for instance is as the supremum of the set of subsequential limits obtained from the original sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\sup_{k\geq n}x_k$. Then the usual definition of limit superior is that $\limsup x_n=\lim a_n$. Suppose $\limsup x_n=\lim a_n=+\infty$. Then for any $m>0$, there exists $N$ such that $a_n>m$ for all $n\geq N$.

Choose $m$ systematically in the following way: Starting with $m=1$, there exists $n_1$ such that $a_{n_1}>1$. By definition, this means $1$ is not an upper bound for the set $\{x_k:\, k\geq n_1\}$. Hence, there exists $x_{k_1}$ such that $1<x_{k_1}\leq a_{n_1}$.

Proceeding inductively, by setting $m=1,2,\dots, l,\dots$. See if you can finish the proof by constructing a subsequence explicitly that diverges to $+\infty$.